# What is required to run two monitors off one machine

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

Hello All and looking for a little insight. My DELL XPS 8500 desktop has TWO HDMI connection ports. Though only one has the complete inners to secure a connection. Directly to the left is the pin connection for a VGA cable that requires an adaptor that came with it.

The missing connection tab in the other HDMI port leads me to believe I need another video card?? I am learning and this is just my/a guest. It has been days with no reply from DELL or their community. Also their pdf for this model does not show the ports that my unit has available.

If I run the VGA to one monitor it displays an output. When I run the HDMI to the other monitor it duplicates the output on it. I am on Windows 10 and from SETTING > Display I get to the identify / detect options. Using the options I can only get a duplicate on both screens. Or one blank and the other with my desktop start screen.

Does what is explained mean I have one video card, I need a dual card to run each monitor with their own output. I would like to have an IED or Design program running on one. With the other reserved for documents, video tutorial/YouTube for learning purposes.  I have a few screen shots of the back panel showing HDMI situation.

What I have been doing is running my desktop into a 42" Vizio TV, while running my laptop into a different 36" Vizio TV. It make getting to reference materials easier without getting lost with open tabs and minimizing and split-screening. Though not very power friendly and very hot, but through the winter my work space is very comfy. Please review the photos and please note the extra VGA and HDMI port that is elevated away from the main connections ports. Running either monitor off the HDMI does not produce a visual output. I get retrieving data dialog box like the TV is looking for a recognized signal. Then after 15 second outputs NO Signal Found, making me believe this is for a Xbox or Play Station / Component.

[image: Available connection *NOTE HDMI*]

Comment: "What is required to run two monitors off one machine" A dual head video card.

Comment: With both monitors connected and detected, there's no "Extend" option under "Multiple displays"? Also, there is no "other HDMI port". There's only one HDMI port in that picture and possibly a DP port.

Comment: I get my start screen on one and can navigate Bing home page, Facebook and the other monitor has my desktop wallpaper. There is no task bar icons, Windows icon or any of the saved to desktop shortcuts.... I have some above basic skills but stumped with this. Thanks for your reply

Comment: That probably means it's in spanned mode, you should be able to drag a window over to the other screen. And I concur with David Schwartz that the port on the right side of your video card is definitely a DisplayPort connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a DP to HDMI adapter and from Settings in Windows10 established a desktop image on both monitors. I am new to Windows10 and required a few You Tube videos to provide a full explaination on how to use them properly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your information, your main monitor works and your secondary monitor has nothing except your wallpaper, which means you set up an extended monitor configuration successfully. Good job.

If you drag a window to the right of your primary monitor, it should appear by default on your second monitor.

If your second monitor isn't on the right, though, you can go to the display settings and simply drag the box representing the second monitor to the left of your primary monitor. Now when you drag a window, Windows will honor the position of your second monitor, so you can drag a window in the correct direction and it will appear on your second monitor.

Comment: Hello to all 3 of you guys and thank you ALL for your time. Yes it has been sometime since I first posted this. I had been out of town for 6 weeks and then with Hurrican Matthew going through my location here in Florida. Daul monitors have been on the back burner. I have a DP to HDMI adaptor on route from Amazon as the VGA cable I have is a monster. I learned what a Display Port Connecter is!! I will apply your inputs when I get it and hope that does the trick. Thanks for your answers and will post a simple message if it is successful. Thanks again for your time and sharing...Peace.....